# Why the program crased even thoungh I got the correct result?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value

I am learning the data structure of LinkList, and I have already implemented the source code that works for me. Today I try to do it in another way like below. And I am confusing why the programe will be crashed even though I get the result I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define OK 1
#define ERROR 0

typedef int ElemType;
typedef int Status;

typedef struct LNode
{
    ElemType data;
    struct LNode *next;
}LNode, LinkList;   //I don't use the *LinkList on purpose to check it out

//Initialize LinkList: Create a head node
Status InitList(LinkList *L)
{
    L = malloc(sizeof(LinkList));
    if(!L) return ERROR;
    L->next = NULL;

    return OK;
}

//CreateList
Status CreateListHead(LinkList *L, int n)
{
    LinkList *s;
    int i;

    if(n < 1) return ERROR;
    InitList(L);
    srand(time(0));

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        s = malloc(sizeof(LinkList));
        if(!s)  return ERROR;
        s->data = rand()%10+1;
        s->next = L->next;
        L->next = s;
    }

    return OK;
}

//Travese LinkList
void Traverse(LinkList *L)
{
    while(L->next)
    {
        printf("%d ", L->next->data);
        L->next = L->next->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LinkList *L;
    int s;

    s = InitList(L);
    if(s) printf("Successful！");
    else printf("Failed!");

    CreateListHead(L, 10);

    Traverse(L);
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is: Succesful! 1 6 4 6 1 1 8 2 8 2
And then the program crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, whatever memory you allocate to `L` inside `InitList()`, is not going to be reflected back to the actual argument passed to the function when being called.

So, in your code

```
if(n < 1) return ERROR;
InitList(L);               ----------------(1)
srand(time(0));

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    s = malloc(sizeof(LinkList));
    if(!s)  return ERROR;
    s->data = rand()%10+1;
    s->next = L->next; -------------------(2)
    L->next = s;
}
```

at point (2), `L` is still uninitialized. Accessing that will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

C uses pass-by-value, so if you have to modify the argument *itself*, you need to pass a pointer to that. Something like

```
InitList(&L);
```

and then,

```
Status InitList(LinkList **L)
{
    *L = malloc(sizeof(**L));
    if(!*L) return ERROR;
    (*L)->next = NULL;

    return OK;
}
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `InitList` initializes a local copy of `L`, but not the `L` that is in your `main` function. Change it to `InitList(LinkList **L)` and call as `InitList(&L);`, and change your implementation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually pretty surprised that it happens to work on your machine in the first place.  (It's what's technically known as [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and can manifest itself in a variety of ways, including no visible symptomps.)

Anyway, one immediate issue is in `InitList`: when you set `L` there, the newly allocated pointer does not propagate back the caller.  For that you need to turn it into a pointer to pointer:

```
Status InitList(LinkList **L)
{
    *L = malloc(sizeof(LinkList));
    if(!*L) return ERROR;
    (*L)->next = NULL;

    return OK;
}
```

You'll then need to call it like so:

```
InitList(&L);
```